# Push modifications from a downloaded git repo

Tags: git, merge

A colleague started working in one of our git repositories by downloading the project from gitlab instead of doing a checkout. I want to commit/push his modifications, but it's problematic and I'm not sure what the best course of action is (I'm not a git expert either).

- `git status` shows *every* file as modified because the permissions aren't the same. `git config core.filemode false` did help with that
- `git commit -a` seems to work but the push gets rejected "the remote contains work that you do not have locally"
- `git pull` leads to lots of conflicts "both modified"
- `git merge -Xours` gives me "Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files"
- `git checkout --ours -- .` get rid of the <<<< but then
- `git status` still shows files as "both modified" and I can't commit.

I'm not sure what to do at this stage to commit and push all 'ours'

Comment: wait. are you asking us how to merge changes we've not seen to a codebase we've not seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listing things you tried to resolve the situation, but it seems you did not properly abort the merge resulting from the `git pull` and further attempts have been ineffectual because of it. First `git merge --abort`, then you'll be able to try a different merge, or anything.

**edit after comments :**

OK then. So after the `--abort`, go for

```
git merge -s ours <branch>
```

...if you indeed want only one part to take over, overwriting any changes on the other side, or alternatively

```
git merge -Xours <branch>
```

to keep *both* sides' modifications, but always choosing "ours" side *on conflicting parts*.

(However, I'd suggest doing a normal merge in the first place and resolve conflicts manually, unless you're really sure of the result you want.)

Comment: Instead of `pull`, try `git fetch` and then merge the two branch heads.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I was specifically adressing the reasons OP's attempts were failing. But yes, this is a good way to start for the actual resolution. Although we still don't know much about the desired result, and which side has valuable/disposable code.

Comment: If that wasn't clear from the 'ours' in my attempts, I want to keep his code and there shouldn't be any real conflict because different files have been changed on both sides. Will try your suggestions.

Comment: @dargaud OK, thanks for the clarification, I've edited.

Comment: I needed a few tries and a few more git commands, but it eventually worked that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try `git format-patch` to "copy" each commit to a correctly cloned repo.

Think of it as a manual version of cherry picking.

Comment: I produced a patch as you said, by trying to apply it: `$ git am 0001-Ludo-tests.patch
error: patch failed: Source/HhldBoustrophedon.c:149
error: Source/HhldBoustrophedon.c: patch does not apply
error: Source/HhldLudoTest.c: already exists in index...`

Comment: @dargaud "index" is the place where Git remembers files that should be part of the next commit. If you get this error, then you have started to prepare a commit with "git add" or you're in the middle of a merge. My approach only works in a clean git repo (i.e. where `git status` shows nothing).